# What could be the problem with inserting the query from localhost database?

Tags: php

I am working on getting active users on a localhost server. While I came up with an error. I am providing the portion which is not working in PHP MySQL:

I changed `$REMOTE_ADDR`, `$PHP_SELF` to `$_SERVER['$REMOTE_ADDR']`, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` as those are old version of PHP. Still not getting expected result.

```
$timestamp = time();

//insert the values
$insert = mysql_db_query($database, " INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('$timestamp', $_SERVER['$REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] )" );
```

the error goes like this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in G:\xampp\htdocs\jencyphp\liveonline\online.php on
>   line 21

Comment: Did you try an online sql validator, e.g. https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/?

Comment: I am working on it.....

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*()`, it's deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Although you should use prepared statements, try building the string by concatanation... `'$timestamp', '". $_SERVER[$REMOTE_ADDR]."`

Comment: I am looking for a solution... Glad as it was duplicate...  Nigel Ren Appreciate your help. Found my solution

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check by doing this. You are missing database table fields name in query so you must need to add that fields.

```
$timestamp = time();

$insert = mysql_db_query($database, "INSERT INTO mytable (`field1`,`field2`,`field3`) VALUES('".$timestamp."','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."')");
```

Comment: Checking...2 minutes

Comment: No Luck .......

Comment: It's still the same error.....

Comment: Although I would usually add the column names in to ensure the values go in the right fields, they are not necessary.

Comment: @Jency : I have updated answer. check it now. it will work for you.